# How to convert floating value to integer with exact precision like 123.3443 to 1233443?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, floating-point-precision

Sample code:

```
int main() {
  float f = 123.542;
  int i = (int)f;
  printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: What if the number is `1.999999999999`? Hint: What you're trying do is not possible. (or at least it's poorly defined with binary floating-point)

Comment: Perhaps what you want is to get as much of a float to the left of some portion which is close to zero (with some tolerance)?

Comment: @Mysticial: It's actually always possible with floating-point, as the FP exponent is a power of 2. The results will just usually not be what you want (e.g, it'll only work for exact binary fractions).

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit IEEE float, the exact decimal value of f in your example will be 123.54199981689453125. That is not what would be printed by printf, because it uses a heuristic which prints the shortest representation that, if parsed back to float, would give you the exact same float. I mention this to point out that others are correct that your question might not be well formed enough to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 11):

123.3443 can't be exactly represented by a floating-point number -- in a 32-bit float, it's effectively represented as `16166984 / 131072`, which is actually 123.34429931640625, not 123.3443. (It's off by around 6.8 x 10^-7.)

If this is really the result you want (which it's probably not), take a look at how IEEE-754 floats work, and pull out your favorite arbitrary-precision math suite. Once you understand what's going on "behind the scenes", generating an exact representation shouldn't be *too* hard. Generating a "close enough" rounded representation is actually much harder. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = (int) (f * 10000 + 0.5);
```

Comment: Not really generally helpful answer (though asker would get exactly what he asked for). It's (very) probably not what he had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the `float` by `10^x` where `x` is how many digits after the decimal you want and then cast to `int`.

Comment: This will work, but assumes you know the number of decimal places you want in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do any repetitive processing of the converted number and are only looking to convert the numbers into an integer, the easiest way is to use sprintf, then sum up the decimals with a for loop using power of 10 rules. If you need "exact precision" for math, use a BCD. The following algorithm will allow you to truncate the number of digits for "exact precision".

```
#include "math.h"

long ConvertToScaledInteger (float value, int significantDigits = -1)
{
    // Note: for 32-bit float, use long return and for double use long long.

    if (significantDigits < 1)   // Ditch the '-' and the '.'
        significantDigits += 2;
    else
        ++significantDigits;     // Ditch the '.'

    char* floatingPointString = malloc(sizeof (char) * (4 + FLT_MANT_DIG - FLT_MIN_EXP));
    /*< This solution  is for a 32-bit floating point number. Replace FLT 
         with DBL, and it will produce the max number of chars in a 64-bit 
         float string. */

    if (significantDigits < 0)   //< Then use all of the float's digits.
    {
        sprintf (floatingPointString , "%f", floatingPointNumber);
    }
    else    //< Then truncate the number of decimal places.
    {
        char decimalPlaceString[9];
        char percentString = "%\0";
        sprintf (decimalPlaceString, "%s%if", percentString , significantDigits);
        sprintf (floatingPointString , decimalPlaceString, value);
    }

    int stringLength = strlen (floatingPointString),
        index;
    long returnValue = 0;
    double powerOfTen = 10.0,
        currentValue;

    // Find if we have an ending of .0, and backtrack.
    if (floatingPointString[stringLength - 1] == '0' && floatingPointString[stringLength - 2] == '.')
        index = stringLength - 3;
    else
        index = stringLength - 1;

    for (; index > 0; --index)
    {
        if (floatingPointString[index] == '.')
            --index;

        // Subtract ASCII '0' converts ASCII to integer.

        currentValue = (double) floatingPointString[index] - '0';
        returnValue += (long) currentValue * pow (10.0, powerOfTen);

        powerOfTen += 1.0;
    }

    if (floatingPointString[0] == '-')
        returnValue *= -1;

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why answer with C++ code for a C post?  Recommend porting to C.

Comment: `4 + FLT_MANT_DIG - FLT_MIN_EXP` is too small.  See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644327/how-to-convert-floating-value-to-integer-with-exact-precision-like-123-3443-to-1#comment53280321_32674012)

Comment: `"\%%if"` invalid escape sequence.

Comment: 1) With `int index; ... if (floatingPointString[index - 1]`, index is not initialized.  2) The algorithm has some promise,yet is has to many errors.  Suggest review, test and re-post.

Comment: I see what you were saying. I fixed the errors but the code is not debugged. The max size of the string is correct. This is for a 32-bit float. Replace FLT with DBL and float to double and it will work correctly. See the following Stack Overflow post for max size of float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value

Answer (score 0):

The integer equivalent of a `float` number `f`

```
float f=123.456;
```

can be made using [`modff()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/modf.html) like

```
float integral, fractional;
char str[50], temp[20];
fractional = modff(f, &integral);
```

Now `integral` has the integer part (like 123.000000) and `fractional` has the fractional part (like 0.456000).

If the floating point number (`f` in this case) were negative, both `integral` and `fractional` would be negative.

You can do

```
if(fractional<0)
{
    fractional = -fractional;
}
```

to remedy that.

Now,

```
sprintf(temp, "%g", fractional);
```

The `%g` format specifier will remove the trailing zeros and `temp` will now have `"0.456"`.

```
sprintf(str, "%g%s", integral, temp[1]=='.'?temp+2:"");
```

The `temp[1]=='.'?` is done because if the fractional part were `0`, there would'v been no decimal point while printing `fractional` as it would've been `0` and not `0.000000`. If the second character in `temp` is not `.`, `fractional` is zero and we needn't bother with it.

Now in our case, `str` would be `"123456"`. But that's in the form of a string. We need to convert it into an integer. Use `strtol()` for that.

```
long l=strtol(str, NULL, 10);
if(l>INT_MAX || errno==ERANGE)
{
    printf("\noverflow");
}
else
{
    printf("\n%d", strtol(str, NULL, 10));
}
```

You may check the return value of `strtol()` and that of `errno` (from `errno.h`. Check whether it is `ERANGE` ) to see if overflow occurred.

To see if the resultant value can be stored in an `int`, first store the value returned by `strtol()` in a `long int` and see if that is greater than `INT_MAX` (it's in `limits.h`).

It should be noted that the accuracy of the result will depend upon the accuracy with which the floating point number is represented in binary.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int f2i(float v, int size, int fsize){
    char *buff, *p;
    int ret;
    buff = malloc(sizeof(char)*(size + 2));
    sprintf(buff, "%*.*f", size, fsize, v);
    p = strchr(buff, '.');
    while(*p=*(p+1))p++;
    ret = atoi(buff);
    free(buff);
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    float f = 123.3443;

    printf("%d\n", f2i(f, 7, 4));

    f=123.542;
    printf("%d\n", f2i(f, 6, 3));
    return 0;
}
```