# Convert a float into a string in c

Tags: c, floating-point, char, systems-programming

I am writing a function that will be passed a float in the form of a void pointer. What I am attempting to do, is convert that float into a string equivalent so that I might save that binary data in memory. For example, the call to my function is as follows:

```
void * f(void * data);
```

If a user passes me

```
float value = 3.14;
```

I would like to convert it into a string as shown below:

```
"3.14"
```

The approach that I think I should use, would be to first determine the number of values within the float: 3.14 = four values. I would then have to loop through each value and convert it to a character.

A couple problems I am having, is 1: I'm not sure if it is even possible to determine the number of values associated with a given float. 2: How would I convert each value into its string equivalent?

I came across itoa and sprintf. However, itoa isn't part of the standard C libary, and I am unsure as to whether or not sprintf will do as I desire.

Comment: sprintf(str, "%4.2f", float)

Comment: You probably want `sprintf`. You can't (generally) figure out a number of digits -- something that's passed as (for example) `1.2` will end up as something on the order of `1.99999999999999` (out to the precision of the type -- but binary floating point can't represent `0.2` precisely.

Answer (score 3):

Most systems (in particular POSIX ones) have `snprintf` (and `strdup`) so you could code

```
 char buf[48];
 snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "%f", x);
```

if you want to return that string, `strdup` it (then you'll need to `free` the result of `strdup` later).

PS: `sprintf` is more dangerous than `snprintf` because it could overflow the buffer

Comment: and remember to free the buffer(from `strdup()`) later.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that the float could never be larger than the buffer if the buffer is allocated with 48 bytes?

Comment: A `float` is 4 bytes on most PCs; a `double` is 8 bytes; the result of `snprintf` then `strdup` may have more than a dozen of bytes (and `malloc`-ed memory like the result of `strdup` often have some overhead).

Comment: `snprintf` is part of the C standard since 1999.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't think the size of the `float` has much of a connection to the size of its string representation. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value) computes the max # of chars for a `double` to be 1078. Which is a lot.

Comment: I do know that the size of a `float` is not much related to the size of its string representation.