# c++ formatting float with automatic precision

Tags: c++, floating-point

Is there a standard way of formatting a float (or double) in C++ in decimal with exactly enough precision to parse it back to the same bits?

That is, I want `1.F` to be `"1.0"` and `2.002f` to be `"2.002"`.

For cases, where decimal is inexact another format would be acceptable (scientific or even hex float).  Does such a case exist?

All I can find is reference to `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` 
[such as this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).  The precision is fixed for these.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, and I assume you're asking about actual normalized numbers outside of bit patterns that represent [denormals and infinity and NaNs](http://www.randelshofer.ch/fhw/gri/float.html)?

Comment: Related question: [What is the maximum length in chars needed to represent any double value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value)

Comment: I think this might help: [std::numeric_limits::digits10](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

Comment: One cannot represent `2.002` exactly as `float` or `double`. For `float` case something like `2.0020000934600830078125` is actually stored.

Comment: Also, how do you want to numbers like `1e-32` to be represented? If it does not have to be human readable I would vote for dumping `float`'s bytes as hex.

Comment: I would strongly advise using hexfloats if you can: not only are they assured to be lossless, but they are significantly (often up to 10x) faster to read/write.

Answer (score 2):

I have to do exactly that a lot, i.e., what you are trying to do. My solution is to use something like this:

```
char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "%.15f", v);
TrimTrailingZeros(buf);
```