# Sscanf a double value

Tags: c, double, scanf

I need scan a double from a string, can you help me? It need to be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    const char *key="infinity";
    const char *str = malloc(2*sizeof(double*));
    double a;
    printf("Write the value: "
    scanf("%s",str);
    if (strcmp(str,key)==0)
        printf ("ok");
    else
    {
        sscanf(str,"%lf",&a);
        printf("ok, a is %lf",a);
    }
    return 0;
```

When I put infinity, it works properly. But when I enter with some `double` value (like 1.25), it doesn't.

```
1.25
ok, a is 0.000000
```

Comment: Why are you using the value `2*sizeof(double*)` for the length of the string?

Comment: I think you need to start over with [a few good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: No reason for that. I just wanted allocate sufficient memory.

Comment: How much memory do you require for the string? What is the value that you gave? Why are you using the size of a double for a string?

Comment: @user435800 - Please do not edit the question in such a way that answers/comments stop making sense.

Comment: I just wanted allocate some memory.

Comment: @user435800 - Just append an update to the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First all, there is a way you should check if the line of code runs successfully or not.

You are using `sscanf()`, check it's return value to be sure if it is being successful in what it is supposed to do. (To get the double from `str`).

Also why `const char*`. It is pointing to an `immutable` character string. You can't change it's value. So the first `scanf` will fail. You can simply use `char*` here, that will be sufficient for your requirement.

Allocating `2*sizeof(double*)` doesn't ensure that you will be able to hold all the digits of a double number. That's a wrong idea. You can consider a rough value to hold (like upto 12 digits after decimal point) and then scan it.

Considering the return value of `malloc` is another good practice. In case it fails it returns `NULL`. And after getting `NULL` if you go on accessing it, then it invokes undefined behavior.

Whatever you allocate using `malloc`, it's need to be freed after you are done working with it.

Also read some good books. There are plenty of them.

A small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char *trimwhitespace(char *str)
{
  char *end;


  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)
    return str;

  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;

  *(end+1) = 0;

  return str;
}
int main()
{
    const char *key="infinity";
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*(3 + DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP+1));
    if( str == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *store = str;
    double a;
    printf("Write the value: ");
    if( fgets(str, (3 + DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP+1), stdin) == NULL){           
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in string input");
        exit(1);
    }
    str = trimwhitespace(str);
    if( strlen(str) == 0){
         printf("Empty line detected.\n");
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for(size_t i = 1; i < strlen(str); i++){
        if( !isspace(str[i]) && isspace(str[i-1])){
            printf("Error extra input detected\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    }
    if (strcmp(str,key)==0)
        printf ("ok");
    else
    {
        char *err;

        a = strtod(str, &err);
        if (*err!=0 && !isspace((unsigned char)*err)) { 
            printf("Error extra input detected ");
        }
        else{
            printf("ok, a is %lf",a);
        }

    }
    free(store);
    return 0;
}
```

### Reference:

**†** After finding a bit I could finally cite the correct reference for the `3 + DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP` part. Check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value)**.