# Maximum allowed value of the precision format specifier in the {fmt} library

Tags: c++, fmt

Consider the following snippet<sup>1</sup> (which is testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kq1ahh6Pa)):

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// Let's see how many digits we can print
void test(auto value, char const* fmt_str, auto std_manip, int precision)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std_manip << std::setprecision(precision) << value;
    auto const std_out { oss.str() };
    auto const fmt_out { fmt::format(fmt_str, value, precision) };    
    std::cout << std_out.size() << '\n' << std_out << '\n'
              << fmt_out.size() << '\n' << fmt_out << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto const precision{ 1074 };
    auto const denorm_min{ -0x0.0000000000001p-1022 };

    // This is fine
    test(denorm_min, "{:.{}g}", std::defaultfloat, precision);
    
    // Here {fmt} stops at 770 chars
    test(denorm_min, "{:.{}f}", std::fixed, precision);  
}
```

According to the `{fmt}` library's [documentation](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html):

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating-point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating-point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`.

Is there a limit to this value?

In the corner case I've posted, `std::setprecision` seems to be able to output all of the
requested digits, while `{fmt}` seems to stop at 770 (a "reasonably" big enough value in most cases, to be fair). Is there a parameter we can set to modify this limit?

**EDIT**

I reported the [issue](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2616) to the library mantainers and it appears to have been [fixed](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/commit/c472a2781852778cc3f06521a3384a2c5c5822d5), now.

---

<sup>(1) If you are wondering where those particular values come from, I was playing with this Q&A:

[What is the maximum length in chars needed to represent any double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far off, there is a hardcoded limit of 767 in the `format-inl.h` file ([see here](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/012cc709d0abb0a963591413a746b988168e5e3a/include/fmt/format-inl.h#L2380)):

```
// Limit precision to the maximum possible number of significant digits in
// an IEEE754 double because we don't need to generate zeros.
const int max_double_digits = 767;
if (precision > max_double_digits) precision = max_double_digits;
```

Comment: I see, thanks. The extra 3 chars are the leading `"-0."`, in my example. Not sure where they get that "magic" number of maximum significant digits from, though.

Comment: If you believe that the value should be higher (or modifiable), then can add a bug to the issue tracker on their GitHub or submit a pull request, the maintainers should be able to tell you where the number comes from

Answer (score 4):

Precision can be any value less than max `int`.

What you observed was a now fixed bug in handling very large precision in fixed floating-point format: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/2616 (thanks for reporting it).

767 is not a precision limit but the maximum number of significant digits IEEE754 double can have (the rest will be zeros): https://www.exploringbinary.com/maximum-number-of-decimal-digits-in-binary-floating-point-numbers/.

Comment: That was fast, thank you very much. I eventually figured out the meaning of that number, but again, thanks for the reference. If I may, am I correct assuming that there isn't a format specifier that would automatically output *all* the significant digits (including the leading zeroes) of the decimal representation, but *without* the trailing zeroes (which are outputted using a big enough precision value)?

Comment: Not for fixed precision but the default format will give you enough significant digits for round trip (the rest is mostly meaningless).