# What is the maximum string length for %g float representation?

Tags: c, string, floating-point, printf

How big does a stack allocated string need to be in order to store any float/double in %g format?

```
int main()
{
    float f;
    double d;
    
    char f_str[ ?? ];
    char d_str[ ?? ];
    
    sprintf(f_str, "%g",  f);
    sprintf(d_str, "%lg", d);
}
```

Edit:

I want the string size to be known at compile-time, such that I don't rely on heap allocation or VLAs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length in chars needed to represent any double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701055/what-is-the-maximum-length-in-chars-needed-to-represent-any-double-value)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the difference is `%g`stores either in scientific notation (`%e`) or in decimal (`%f`). Whichever is shortest, I want the stack allocated string to be as small as possible to store the float/double.

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how many significant digits you want to print.  If you don't specify a precision, it defaults to 6.

Comment: Are you sure you're not over-optimizing? You're talking about a few bytes.

Comment: @dbush that's after decimal point. I'm asking about the whole string. How big does the string need to be, to store a `%g` representation of a float/double

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi *"that's after decimal point"*  No, for `%g` it's the total number of significant digits.

Comment: @dbush so you're saying the string has to be 6 characters in order to represent any float value?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi If you don't explicitly give a precision, it will print up to 6 significant digits.  Then you need to add space for a possible minus sign plus any exponent specifier, i.e. `-1e+5`.

Comment: I wonder if there could be any longer strings than for `-FLT_MAX`, `-DBL_MAX` and `-LDBL_MAX`? Common values (but not set in stone) are `-3.40282e+38` (13 chars), `-1.79769e+308` (14 chars) and `-1.18973e+4932` (15 chars). [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PjdsqzEzK)

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, No, since `%g` doesn't print all the digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the maximum string length for %g float representation?

13 when values are within 10<sup>+/- 999</sup>

15 with [binary128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)

---

For extreme values `"%g"`, uses exponential notation.

`"%g"`, lacking a *width* or precision, will print with 6 significant digits.

Long expected form:

```
[sign][digit].[5 digits]e[sign][expo_digits]
   1     1   1    5     1   1       3        --> 13
```

Example:

```
//           1234567890123
DBL_TRUE_MIN -4.94066e-324
```

---

- when `double` has a wider exponent range, additional space needed.
- NAN may print something longer.  Much is implementation defined.  A reasonable worst case form would estimate it as "-sNAN" *decimal payload*" The payload of [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) may be 16 decimal places.

---

> How big does a stack allocated string need to be in order to store any float/double in %g format?

If seeking a *constant*, given the exponent range, in decimal, may be more than 3 digits and NANs may print a payload, I would scale on NAN payload printing as that is certainly a worst case.  Use the significand size in bits to determine the decimal payload by scaling by log10(2).

```
#define DBL_SIZE (sizeof(double)*CHAR_BIT)
#define LOG10_2_NUM 302
#define LOG10_2_DEN 1000
#define DBL_PAYLOAD (DBL_MANT_DIG*LOG10_2_NUM/LOG10_2_DEN)
#define DBL_G_SIZE (5 /* -sNAN */ + DBL_PAYLOAD + 1 /* \0 */ )
```

Thus a buffer size of 22 for common `double`.

---

Given all the potential implementation define attributes, I'd use `snprintf()`.

```
 char buf[DBL_G_SIZE];
 int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%g", x);
 assert(len > 0 && (unsigned) len < sizeof buf);
```

Comment: I am thinking `#define DBL_PAYLOAD (DBL_MANT_DIG*LOG10_2_NUM/LOG10_2_DEN)` should be  `... DBL_MANT_DIG*LOG10_2_NUM/LOG10_2_DEN + 1)`.  Will ponder.

Comment: Assuming IEEE-754 standard. 13 + 1 buffer size for floats, and 21 + 1 for doubles, would be sufficient to represent any value in `%g` format, is that correct?

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi Those sizes are reasonable.  If you use `char buf[DBL_G_SIZE * 2];`, there would be little downside.  The point is that we should not be stingy in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [snprintf()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) to calculate the exact length you need for your specific format string and value(s)

```
float f = 3.14159265358979;
int f_len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%g", f);
char f_str[f_len + 1]; // or malloc...
sprintf(f_str, "%g", f); // it fits
// remember to free if you malloc'd before
```

Comment: but `f_len` is now a runtime value, making `f_str` a VLA

Comment: That is correct @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi. In this particular case the string will not be large enough to be a potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on both the actual floating-point format and the current locale since some characters such as the decimal-point character may take several bytes. For instance, if `double` corresponds to the IEEE 754 binary64 format (a.k.a. double precision), the maximum string length (as a number of bytes) is 13 under the C locale, but it may be 14 in practice (and I don't even think that there is a limit from the C standard).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

static void f (void)
{
  char s[256];
  double x = -DBL_MAX;
  printf ("%g\n", x);
  sprintf (s, "%g", x);
  printf ("%zu\n", strlen (s));
}

int main (void)
{
  f ();
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "ps_AF");
  f ();
  return 0;
}
```

On my Debian Linux machine (where all the locales are enabled), I get:

```
-1.79769e+308
13
-1٫79769e+308
14
```

The 14 is due to the U+066B ARABIC DECIMAL SEPARATOR used for the decimal-point character in the ps_AF locale (based on UTF-8), encoded as D9 AB.

The answer is similar for `long double`, but you need to know the minimum and maximum exponents of the associated format.